# Is this an illegal syntax

Tags: bash

I am attempting to write a script that will generate a random number and then make a directory called that random number and copy in a text file. I have tried everything i could think of the assign the variable but each time i get

```
RANDOM: command not found
RANDOM: command not found
bash: //small.txt: No such file or directory
bash: //small.txt: No such file or directory
```

Below is my code

```
#!/bin/bash
one=$(RANDOM)
two=$(RANDOM)

mkdir -p $one
mkdir -p $two
echo “BIGGGGGONgrery54y457457yytewrterytyutytytyhtytryrtyrthrthtrhrtyhrthrhtrhrthrthrthrthE”| > $one/small.txt
echo “B”| > $two/small.txt
echo "finish -l test me "
done
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not *illegal* syntax (it does mean something), it's just the wrong syntax for what you want.  Instead of `$(RANDOM)` you want `${RANDOM}` or even just `$RANDOM`.

When you use `$()` it's a command substitution, so bash is literally trying to execute a command named `RANDOM`, which is why you get command not found and nothing in your variables.

Your I/O redirection also looks wrong... to write to a file you should use:

```
echo "something" > file
```

Note that I removed the `|`.

Comment: I urgently need a coffee. I was unable to see it :-)

Answer (score 1):

FatalError covered the syntax problem, here's something related - how to generate a random number within a range (in this example, 1-100):

```
NUMBER=$(( ( $RANDOM % 100 )  + 1 ))
```

Also see: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-shell-script-generating-random-numbers/ for other methods / information about random number generation in shell

Comment: Note: better to use `$((...))` over `$[...]` -- the bash manpage says:  *The old format $[expression] is deprecated and will be removed in upcoming versions of bash.*